# How to search for 2 patterns and limit them at the same time?

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep

How to search for 2 patterns and limit them at the same time?

example:
I have 50 lines, 25 has "kernel" in it, another 25 has "audit". How can I filter out the output so i get 5 lines of each with a single command? Is it possible with grep?

Comment: you mean 5 lines have both kernel and audit in it?

Comment: nah I meant I need 10 lines, 5 with kernel and 5 with audit separately.

Comment: just the first 5 matches for each?

Comment: I think this does the trick, using awk: [Need to grep for first occurrences of multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204958/need-to-grep-for-first-occurrences-of-multiple-strings)

Comment: Does kernel and audit appear on the same line? If yes, what to do with it? print it for each audit and kernel or just once?

Comment: @pLumo They never appear on the same line. I want to print 10 lines. 5 with audit in it, 5 with kernel in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `awk` ?

```
awk '
     k<5 && /\<kernel\>/ {k++;print}
     a<5 && /\<audit\>/ {a++;print}
' file
```

Or 2 `grep` commands:

```
grep -m 5 -Fw kernel file
grep -m 5 -Fw audit file
```

Leave out the word boundaries from `awk`  and the `-w` from `grep` if you don't want this.

Comment: It worked! thank you!